# How to distinct values on foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays

In my collection I have some foreach that returns some id's **BUT** not as an **array** so `array_unique()` doesn't work in my case. I want to distinct the returned values.

```
foreach ($prodCollection as $prod) {
    $catCollection = getModel()...; //$prod i need it in my collection
    foreach ($catCollection as $col) {
        var_dump($col->getId());
    }
}
```

Result:

```
string(4) "5510"

string(4) "5510"
```

What I need is is `string(4) "5510"` just once.

Comment: where does the data come from? db?

Comment: show us the code from the getModel() function and/or explain how are you getting your data. Is it coming from a database or some other API.

Comment: can you please add sample of your array in question?

Comment: if you don't have control over how the data is fetched, then in this code you'll need to maintain a list of values you've seen before in your loop, and check each entry to know whether you've seen it before, and if so, don't output it again. If you _do_ have control over how the data is fetched into the code you've shown, it might be easier to fix it there instead (e.g. a DISTINCT query in a DB, perhaps). It's not clear.

Comment: use array with keys. Put your values as keys in the array.

Comment: @B001  Yes the data comes from db my collection do some query to the database with filters ofcourse

Comment: @Igor Ilic Yes the data comes from db my collection do some query to the database with filters ofcourse

Comment: _Yes the data comes from db_ So optimize your query to get unique data

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this way.

Check if value is in array or not, if not then add it in array.
That may help.

```
$result = array();
foreach ($prodCollection as $prod) {
    $catCollection = getModel()...; //$prod i need it in my collection
    foreach ($catCollection as $col) {
        if(!in_array($col->getId(), $result)){  // Check if value is in array or not, if not then add it in array.
            $result[]=$col->getId();
        }
        //var_dump($col->getId());
    }
}
```

Comment: The same problem `var_dump($result);` returns two times the value

Comment: @prc this code looks like it ought to work. If you have a problem with it, please show us some sample data with which it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Use array with keys. Put your values as keys in the array. It give same effect as Set

```
$set1 = array ('a' => 1, 'b' => 1, );
```

or

> add the items to an array, then call array_unique to remove duplicates

Answer (score 0):

I just getting this solution as a workaround, It do the trick I don't know if it's the better one !

```
$groupValues = array();
foreach ($prodCollection as $prod) {
    $catCollection = getModel()...; //$prod i need it in my collection
    foreach ($catCollection as $col) {
        array_push($groupValues, $colt->getId());
        var_dump($col->getId());
    }
} 

var_dump(array_unique($groupValues)); // return 5510
```

Comment: Don't push your value into an array if you don't need. Check my answer if it helps.